# Get the status of calendar in Google calendar through api

Tags: google-calendar-api, google-console-developer

I used to get Calendar Name using Calendar ID with the below API call:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/877rak5vqdsj68q52tehukeopg@group.calendar.google.com
```

And then I get a response like

```
{
 """"kind"""": """"calendar#calendar"""",
 """"etag"""": """"\""""ULsH1YPfrSsaWJsYynxh4efocZw/z3mgue7ZR46jHMp-7DrpcXUmmDY\"""""""",
 """"id"""": """"877rak5vqdsj68q52tehukeopg@group.calendar.google.com"""",
 """"summary"""": """"HELLO"""",
 """"description"""": """"HELLO"""",
 """"timeZone"""": """"UTC"""",
 """"conferenceProperties"""": {
 """"allowedConferenceSolutionTypes"""": [
 """"eventHangout""""
   ]
  }
}
```

Now how can I know the status of this calendar, whether it is deleted or not through Google Calendar API. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

If you will check the [CalendarList](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/calendarList/list), a calendar resource have a attribute deleted which can have a boolean value if it is deleted or not.

```
{
  "kind": "calendar#calendarListEntry",
  "etag": etag,
  "id": string,
  "summary": string,
  "description": string,
  "location": string,
  "timeZone": string,
  "summaryOverride": string,
  "colorId": string,
  "backgroundColor": string,
  "foregroundColor": string,
  "hidden": boolean,
  "selected": boolean,
  "accessRole": string,
  "defaultReminders": [
    {
      "method": string,
      "minutes": integer
    }
  ],
  "notificationSettings": {
    "notifications": [
      {
        "type": string,
        "method": string
      }
    ]
  },
  "primary": boolean,
  "deleted": boolean,
  "conferenceProperties": {
    "allowedConferenceSolutionTypes": [
      string
    ]
  }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I see that "showDeleted" parameter needs to be passed for that. So since calendarList api is a GET connection, how do i pass this parameter?